# Character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "WMSYS.WM_CONCAT_IMPL", line 30

Tags: group-by, oracle10g, group-concat

I have tried to  group the multiple rows into a single rows using `WM_CONCAT` function using `Oracle 10g`.

But when running my query, I am getting the following error:

**ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "WMSYS.WM_CONCAT_IMPL", line 30
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s**

Output of my query is :

5319|   64764011907| `6893,1109,1120,1297,1327` (**Need Comma separated list of store for a client id**)

I will not be able to create the types- lack of previliges.

Please let me know if I can do the grouping using some different method in Oracle 10g.

Comment: Is the total length of your list more than 4000 bytes?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it comes out to be more than 4000.

Comment: Then you can't use `wm_concat` (which is also undocumented in 10g).  What privileges do you have?

Comment: What alternative option i can use in place of wm_concat then. I can just simply run DMLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Hall has a pretty canonical list of [string aggregation techniques in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).  Unfortunately, I don't believe that any of them are going to work for you if the result needs to be able to exceed 4000 bytes and you cannot create any sort of object in the database and you're using 10.2.  The `sys_connect_by_path` approach would be the only one worth testing but that's almost certainly [limited to 4000 bytes](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:926509800346493068#5929322600346402541) as well.

If you have access to the various XML functions, you could potentially [use the `xmlagg` function to produce a CLOB](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2484825?tstart=0).